# What items need to dispose when closing activity?

Tags: java, android, xamarin

What elements need to dispose when i'm closing an activity?
I'm using lists,sqlite,recyclerview,listview and so on. If i will call finish inside an activity, doesnt dispose all my activity elements-objects even they are not null?

```
finish();
finishAffinity();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, java's garbage collector will take care of disposing any objects that are not required anymore, however, as @TheWanderer already said, some objects need to be deregistered. Again, please read the docs of the classes you're using as they will indicate if they need some special treatment.

(Hint: Place the cursor in the class name that you want the documentation for and press Ctrl+Q in Android studio to view the documentation)

Answer (score 1):

Certain elements in Android will continue to exist after your Activity has finished, such as BroadcastReceivers.

These elements need to be unregistered when your Activity finishes to avoid things like memory leaks or other weird behavior.

There's no definitive list for this, because it's assumed you will read the documentation of each respective class or API you use and know whether or not it needs to be unregistered/destroyed along with your Activity.